# Augmented reality iOS app in small places - possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, augmented-reality

Is it possible to build an augmented reality iOS app designed to work in small spaces, like a school? I have seen many apps with AR but in big places, like cities. I want to do this in a school - is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do AR anywhere.  Location based AR can get tricky indoors though.  AR uses several tools to determine where you are standing and where you are looking.  These include GPS, Compass, Accelerometer, and Gyroscope.  What you may struggle with is getting a GPS reading with the accuracy needed for a small space, especially inside a building.  I would expect that you will not be able to rely on GPS at all for your application.  So you will need to find some other way to determine location.  You could do some sort of system that relies on stationary QR codes or known points.

Comment: thanks 4 ur explanation.  I have seeing some sites and I need to use an external SDK to develop this and use some tool like unity...is this correct? Do you know some starting point?

Comment: You will want to find a good open source library to help out.  I haven't personally done any AR work so I'm not sure where the best starting place is.

Answer (score 3):

Following is the link for ARTool Kit. This helps you a lot...

https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible. You can create an augmented reality app anywhere. Why wouldn't it work in a school?

Comment: I had never work with AR, so i dun know how it works. I thought that ir works with the GPS, but now i guess not. What tool, feature or API do you use to do this?